# How do I find a software engineering job in the Bay Area in the U.S. as a foreigner?

Tags: software-industry, united-states

I am 28 years old with ~8 years experience in Web Development and a decent B.Sc. in Computer Science. I am working for an internationally recognized company in Germany. I work as senior software developer in an international team (Germany/U.K./India) in an English speaking role. My current employer does not employ software engineers in the U.S.

I would love to work in the U.S., particularly on the West Coast in Web Development. I always wanted to live there.

I'm not sure how to approach this though. Especially given the fact that I only have the German citizenship.

Comment: You typically need a US company to sponsor you for an H1B visa. A google of "H1B Sponsorship California" should give you an idea of what might be available.